# Is there any way to decrease the IDF factor in the relevancy score for Solr?

Tags: solr

Context: We are seeing users use location names in the keyword search for medical practices and any practice that has the location name in the name of the practice and is only 2-3 words showing up higher even if they are not very relevant.

We are boosting matches on the name of the practice. For example, when practice name has "Heart" in their name, searches for "Heart", it should show up first. But, lots of practices also have names that are like "Chicago Medicine" and when somebody searches for "chicago heart", this shows up to the top. Assuming Chicago Medicine also does heart health stuff. i.e. it is an AND search already.

Comment: I assume that you have address details with zip code. If yes you can first check address details for the record to get required practice details. The other option can be to first identify that entered keyword matched with any location or not if yes then use Location API to get all zip codes and then use Solr to get all records which have those zip codes.

Comment: Thanks. Was trying to make it simpler :) But makes sense.